Time Series Cross Validation by skicit learn and Cross Validation by Prophet
I have confusion between time series cross validation by skicit learn and cross validation by Prophet. So I'm trying to compare lstm algorithm with prophet and method The split data used for LSTM is time series cross validation, while for Prophet cross validation. Is this the same thing? If different, which parameters of cross validation are in order what should I adjust to match the n_splits =5 that I have implemented in LSTM?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
